# How can I construct the derivative matrix for an irregular domain?

Tags: differential-equations, programming, mesh

I wish to construct the derivative matrix corresponding to an irregular set of points. For example, I have the following grid consisting 16 nodes in the 2D plane:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
grid = {{-2.30259, 2.40259}, {-2.30259, 2.70259}, {-2.30259, 
   3.00259}, {-2.30259, 3.30259}, {-0.310155, 0.410155}, {-0.310155, 
   0.710155}, {-0.310155, 1.01015}, {-0.310155, 
   1.31015}, {0.312375, -0.212375}, {0.312375, 0.0876253}, {0.312375, 
   0.387625}, {0.312375, 
   0.687625}, {0.693147, -0.593147}, {0.693147, -0.293147}, {0.693147,
    0.00685282}, {0.693147, 0.306853}};
ListPlot[grid, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

I know about the powerful built-in function `NDSolveFiniteDifferenceDerivative` in Mathematica. So, in order to construct my derivative matrix I do the following which is probably not correct:

```
xgrid2 = Sort@Map[First, grid]
ygrid2 = Sort@Map[Last, grid]
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[{1, 1}, {xgrid2, 
   ygrid2}]["DifferentiationMatrix"]
```

But here since the domain is irregular and there are duplicated values in `xgridg2` direction, then nothing will be attained. If I use `DeleteDuplicates` to remove the duplicates values, then the size of the final differentiation matrix is not $16\times 16$!

I will be grateful if someone let me know for a possible way in Mathematica to construct the differentiation matrix quickly for irregular domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do that with the Finite Element Method.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[grid];
```

This will generate a first order mesh. You can have second order meshes, but not without additional information. This means the location of the mid-side nodes and you'd have to generate the mesh manually. See the [ElementMesh Generation Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) for more information about this topic.

```
(*mesh["Wireframe"]*)
mesh["MeshOrder"]
(* 1 *)
```

If you use a second order mesh, like what you get from `ToElementMesh[Disk[]]` the derivative approximation will be second order.

But let's proceed:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables" -> {u}, 
    "Space" -> {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr}];
coefficients = {"ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{{1, 1}}}}};
initCoeffs = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, coefficients];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"]
```

This will return you a sparse array of size 16x16. For more information I'd like to refer you to the [FEM Programming Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html).

To familiarize yourself with the procedure, you could compare FDM and FEM on a rectangular domain. `mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[]]` and see how things go.

Comment: The answer is very useful although it is based on FEM. Can you please just answer the following question to clarify the procedure? In FD method, the command `NDSolveFiniteDifferenceDerivative[{1, 1}, {xgrid2, ygrid2}]["DifferentiationMatrix"]` of Mathematica uses fourth order approximation and sided formulas for the boundary elements. Accordingly what would be the order of accuracy of this procedure here in the FEM `DiscretizePDE`? May you please write some sentences describing the type of approximations and their orders of accuracy? Can we change the order of accuracy in FEM as well or not?

Comment: @M.J.2, updated answer.